# Why is label in header of continuous form in MS Access not clickable?

Tags: ms-access, events, label

Update ** 
I found that the event is firing but there is no visual clue for the user. Is there a way to make it obvious to user that these labels are clickable.

Adding a gif to illustrate the issue. 
[image]
I looked for an obvious answer on web but I could not find the solution. Hopefully, it is a property setting somewhere.

I have a continuous form with labels in form header. We have an event on double click on one of the labels. However, when the form is displayed, none of the labels are clickable. If it allows us to write events (click / dbl click) then obviously these labels should be clickable.

I looked through the properties of label but there is no "enabled" property. So, question is that how to make the label clickable? I hope it is a simple property setting.

Thanks

Comment: Works fine for me. What version of MS Access are you using? Do other events work?

Comment: Access for Office 365. Nothing in the header is clickable.

Comment: Why use a label and not button?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *is not clickable*? -- 1) The event procedure does not run -- 2) There is no visual feedback on click / doubleclick.

Comment: When we mouse over the label or anywhere in header, there is no visual feedback as if these are not selectable.

Comment: Using labels to provide sort functionality. Adding button(s) will clutter the interface and it should not be necessary.

Comment: So they *are* clickable, they just don't show. You can use Mouse Down/-Up and MouseMove events to show the user that they will accept clicks.

Comment: That is correct. However, mouse move is not really like mover over or mouse leave events. So, there is no easy way to change appearance like mouse hover.

Answer (score 0):

Labels are fine for clickable..i use them a lot to perform various operations like dynamic sorting.
EDIT : because i just noticed it...when textboxes/checkboxes/optionboxes are dropped in a form the labels that are associated with them don't have any events...*you have to put explicitly an unassociated label to have its events exposed*

Comment: Question is that is there a setting or something that makes them clickable or makes them disabled.

Comment: If you want to disable you simply Enabled = False....Enabling/Disabling...controls the click effect on them

Comment: Something i noticed...if you drop a textbox on the form the associated label simply follows the textbox and exposes NO events...so in order to have an active label you have to put in on the form on its own.

Comment: There is no enable property for labels. Enabled is a property available on "data" tab for form controls (text box etc.) but data tab is empty for labels.

Comment: Again...the Enabled is correct...but they are clickable if they are unassociated...i use them all the time for sorting...give it a try...if you don't apply an event to them they are pretty much unclickable since it has no action